# If a Banach space has a countably infinite basis, then it has finite dimension

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, baire-category

I'm solving Ex 3.8.2. in Brezis' book of Functional Analysis. Could you have a check on my attempt?

> Let $(E, | \cdot |)$ be a Banach space. Let $(e_n)$ be a countable basis of $E$, i.e., each $x\in E$ is a finite linear combination of $e_n$'s. Then $E$ is finite dimensional.

**My proof:** We define a sequence of subspaces $$E_n := \operatorname{span} \{e_0, \ldots, e_n\}, \quad n \in \mathbb N.$$

Because $E_n$ is finite-dimensional, it is a closed. By hypothesis, we get $$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} E_n = E.$$

By Baire category theorem, there is $\overline n$ such that $\operatorname{int} (E_{\overline n}) \neq \emptyset$, i.e., there is $a \in \operatorname{int} (E_{\overline n})$. This implies there is $r>0$ such that $\mathbb B(a, r) \subseteq E_{\overline n}$. For each $x\in E$, there is $0< \alpha<1$ such that $\alpha a+(1-\alpha)x \in \mathbb B(a, r)$. Hence $$\alpha a+(1-\alpha)x \in E_{\overline n}.$$ Because $a \in E_{\overline n}$, we get $x \in E_{\overline n}$. Hence $E_{\overline n} = E$. Thus $E$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: I think you mean, if it has a countable basis. If it has a countably infinite basis, then it is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Good work! Clearly, there are Banach spaces which have basis.

Comment: If E was finite dimensional, it would have M dimensions, but then $(e_n)$ with $(1\le n\le M+1)$ could not work.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you meant by "countable basis" finite basis, right?

Comment: @herbsteinberg did you meant that every finite subset of the "basis" $(e_n)$ is linearly independent?

Comment: Proof is fine..

Comment: My statement is simply a note that if E is finite dimensional (M), then it has a finite basis of the same number (M).  Any further 'basis' elements would have to be linear combinations of these.  What is your definition of basis?

Comment: @herbsteinberg I actually mean by "basis" the Hamel basis. I should have be more precise.

Comment: In any case if E has dimension M, there are $E_n$ with $n\gt M$ in the union making up E, so E must have a bigger dimension - contradiction.

Comment: @herbsteinberg You're right. I should have written that $(e_n)$ is a countable subset of $E$ such that each $x \in E$ can be written as a finite linear combination of $e_n$'s.